# 401 Unauthorized uploading to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am tring to use the .Net WebClient object to PUT a file to a sharepoint library using basic authentication, it works in sharepoint 2010 in classic mode but does not work in Sharepoint 2013 in Claims mode.

```
public static void UploadFile(string remoteFileURL, byte[] file)
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        webclient.UploadData(remoteFileURL, "PUT", file);
        webclient.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 401 Unauthorized error is an HTTP status code that means the page you were trying to access can not be loaded until you first log on with a valid user ID and password.

If you received the 401 Unauthorized error, it means that the credentials you entered were invalid for some reason.

In your case you are making a put request. On a browser 401 prompts you to input valid credentials until you click on cancel.

Considering that it worked on SharePoint 2010, these could be the possible errors : -

1. The credentials you are using are not valid in the SharePoint 2013 server
2. SharePoint 2013 server is configured to disable pull requests
3. The user you are trying use does not have access privileges to perform a pull request

From my search on claims mode, I found out that there is a [setup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx) which involves adding/migrating users in claims mode which uses a different form of authentication. I think this might be your issue and you should try to check the validity of credentials and access privileges of user you are working with.

Comment: you suggestion of access made me look closely at the permissions, and found out that NTLM credentials were been lost on 2nd hop as there is a redirection setup from the primary server to the actual sharepoint server

Comment: Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of dependencies:

- Does the account have access?
- Is WebDav a contingency?

[Maybe this link might help, but it requires CSOM C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/http-401-unauthorized-using-the-managed-client-object-model)